# Problem with xRDP on Ubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: 16.04, xrdp

1. On an Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Xenial machine I setup xRDP like this:

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y xrdp mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-notification-daemon
   sudo sed -i.bak '/fi/a #xrdp multiple users configuration \n mate-session \n' /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
   sudo ufw allow 3389
   sudo shutdown -r now
2. Connecting from MS-Win10 look to work as expected:

[image]

3. After inputing login and password information I get this screen:

[image]

4. After a few second I got disconected.

The file **.xsession-errors** look like this:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: upstart-event-bridge pre-start process (42575) terminated with status 1
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (42704) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (42696) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: logrotate main process (42549) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-release main process (42601) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (42698) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity7 pre-start process (42699) terminated with status 143
upstart: indicator-messages main process (42773) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (42774) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (42775) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (42776) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-keyboard main process (42779) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-session main process (42784) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-sound main process (42782) killed by TERM signal
Xsession: X session started for  at mardi 10 mars 2020, 10:16:44 (UTC+0100)
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
localuser:bob being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session-binary[1937]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
gnome-session-binary[1937]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Xsession: X session started for  at mardi 10 mars 2020, 10:17:02 (UTC+0100)
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
localuser:bob being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session-binary[2057]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
gnome-session-binary[2057]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

**Please how can I fix this?**

Comment: FYI: You do realize all flavors of 16.04 inc. MATE are EOL & thus un-maintained, as only Ubuntu server (no desktop) or Unity 7 (default desktop), or Kylin desktop are still supported so security for MATE & all other flavors is all on you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will update the distibution to 18.04 but in the mean time I need to make xrdp work.

Comment: 16.04 isn't off-topic here, because only flavors are EOL (excluding Kylin); my comment was more that because you're using EOL/unsupported/un-maintained software you maybe opening security holes if you're using uncontrolled networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this one seems interesting :-)

**First,** Ubuntu 16.04.x is not EOL...It's a LTS release which will be supported till **2021....**(but I do agree It's an old Ubuntu release and it might be time to move to recent one....like Ubuntu 20.04 releasing today)

**Second,** concerning your issue...hmmmm

**Option 1 - Keep old xrdp package and connect to Mate Desktop**

So, the problem seems related to the fact that the mate-session is not starting properly in remote session....

- Have you tried to login locally on the machine using the mate-session ?
- If this is not working, re-install the mate-desktop software on Ubuntu. Ensure that mate desktop repositories are available on your Ubuntu 16.04 mahcine
- If this is working, check the file /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh and ensure that at bottom of the file, the line **mate-session** is present.

**Option 2 -  Install a newer xrdp version and use the Unity Desktop**

Using previous version of xrdp package, it was not possible to access the Unity Desktop...If you decide to use a more recent xrdp package, you should be able to use the Unity Desktop from the remote session

You can try to use the xrdp-installer-v1.x.sh script to easy and automate the installation of newer xrdp packages on top of Ubuntu 16.04.x and allow you to connect to Unity Desktop.  You can find the script and the instructions on how to use it on this [post](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14093)

Using the script is quite straight forward

**Step 1 - Download the script**

```
wget https://www.c-nergy.be/downloads/xrdp-installer-1.1.zip
```

**Step 2 - Unzip it**

```
unzip xrdp-installer-1.1.zip
```

**Step 3 - Mark it as executable**

```
chmod +x xrdp-installer-1.1.sh
```

**Step 4 - Execute the script with parameters to enable your selected options**

```
./xrdp-installer-1.1.sh -h  (for the help)
./xrdp-installer-1.1.sh     (install xrdp using xrdp ubuntu packages )
./xrdp-installer-1.1.sh -c  (install xrdp from sources )
....
```

As Ubuntu 20.04 is about to be released, expect a new version of the script to be released to fix some minor bugs and include support for Ubuntu 20.04

Please note also that if user A is logged on locally on the PC, the user A will not be able to connect remotely (it will be disconnected after login into the remote session). The user A if connected remotely will not be able to login locally on the machine (login loop). This is a limitation to be aware of

Hope this help Till next time